# No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {www.example.org/documentRequest]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap

I am new using Spring SOAP W. I follow many tutorials and try to adapt my need to these examples, but never work, I had this message: `No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://example/eFatura}documentRequest`

Here is the endpoint

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://example/eFatura", localPart = "DocumentType")
@ResponsePayload
public DocumentReturnType sendDocument(@RequestPayload DocumentType request) {
    DocumentReturnType response = new DocumentReturnType();
    response.setHash("Hash-123");
    response.setMsg("Mesaj-SemaDeneme");
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the class around your method, the problem can not be found. Could be missing @Endpoint annotation for example.

Comment: attach log here how some1 will help you with just piece of code with no meaning. add request n response sample